# Current flow in a BJT transistor

Tags: transistors, bjt

If the following is true:
"When forward biased current in a diode is due to flow of majority carriers and in reverse biased it us due to minority carriers also called leakage current".

I relate this concept to the transistor (BJT) in that current flow can be explained as majority carriers are injected into the base from emitter, these  essentially become minority carriers in base and flow to the collector crossing the reversed bias junction.

So the Question basically is :

Could we say that current in the transistor is due the flow of both majority carriers(from emitter to base) and minority carriers(from base to collector)  in the same direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, that explanation is fine. When BE junction is forward biased, majority carriers in Emitter(electrons) are pushed towards base where those electrons become minority carriers(As base is p - type). As CB junction is reverse biased, the minority carriers (electrons in base) in base has no problem to reach the collector. This is only in NPN transistor.